# Docker container started after the underlying image had been deleted, how is that possible?

Tags: image, docker, containers

I deleted a Docker image and started a stopped container that had been using that image before. And it started. How is that possible? Ideally, a container should not start without its image.

Comment: You can't usually delete images that have containers based on them, running or otherwise.  Can you provide a specific set of steps to reproduce this?

Comment: Most likely you removed the _name_ of the image, but the image ID and its corresponding layers will still be stored if the stopped container still exists.